# Set InnoDB as default engine and set a default collation

Tags: mysql, innodb, configuration, mysql-5.7

What should I do to set InnoDB as the default database engine? 
And is possible to set a default collation when I create a schema and tables (e.g. `utf8mb4`)?

I don't want to have to choose these options every time I create a new database.

I am using MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [`default-storage-engine=InnoDB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine) (Set the default storage engine for tables) and you can even force your customers to use InnoDB with [`enforce_storage_engine=InnoDB`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/server-system-variables/#enforce_storage_engine) (Force the use of a particular storage engine for new tables). `enforce_storage_engine`  is a MariaDB only feature.

Default character set and collation you can set in `my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The other options like default storage engine need also be in `my.cnf` to be permanent.

When you don't specify storage engine, collation and character set, MySQL chooses defaults set by you.